# group rows, count grouped rows and order by grouped rows

Tags: php, sql

I want to make an analytics system for a website and I am trying to row accesed urls from a db, group by url, count grouped rows and order DESC by number of grouped rows.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT url FROM analytic) ORDER by (SELECT DISTINCT url FROM analytic)";
$countQry  = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

while($arr = mysqli_fetch_array($countQry)) {
?>
    <?=$arr['url']?>

<?
    }
?>
```

thanks

Comment: You suppose you want a GROUP BY.

Comment: so is something not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT url, COUNT(url) AS theCount
FROM analytic
GROUP BY url
ORDER BY theCount DESC
```

Here is PHP code for you to use:

```
$sql = "SELECT url, COUNT(url) AS theCount FROM analytic GROUP BY url ORDER BY by theCount DESC";
$countQry  = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($countQry, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['url'], ", ", $row['theCount'];
}
```

Comment: small change needed, "ORDER BY theCount DESC"

Comment: @Pushpendra His original query seems to be ordering by the url, not the count.

Comment: Not sure, but right now it says "and order DESC by number of grouped rows."

Comment: You're correct.  I was going by the original query, which is wrong.  The OP makes this clear.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: how do I echo the counted rows in each group that I row?